# How to create a local map from global one

Tags: ros, octomap, graph, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After runing a slam algorithm I receaved a big map and I dlike to make it smaller- I'd like to use only data that are in 3-5 m around. Is there possibility of deleting a node from octomap graph representing a too far point?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/126206/how-to-create-a-local-map-from-global-one/) by [Wilk](https://answers.ros.org/users/7921/wilk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2014-02-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a clear option. Not sure if you can easy clear with it as you can only specify two corner points.

```
~clear_bbx (octomap_msgs/BoundingBoxQuery)

Clears a region in the 3D occupancy map, setting all voxels in the region to "free"
```

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2014-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wilk](https://answers.ros.org/users/7921/wilk/) on 2014-02-04**:
Thanks for very fast response- I'm searching how to use it :D

**Comment by [Wilk](https://answers.ros.org/users/7921/wilk/) on 2014-02-04**:
Maby a stupid question but how can I use it in terminal?

**Comment by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on 2014-02-05**:
Try it with tab completion, it will give the required format.

**Comment by [Wilk](https://answers.ros.org/users/7921/wilk/) on 2014-02-09**:
I think the  usage is like this:  rosrun octomap_server octomap_eraser_cli.py -x -y -z x y z
but still I can't use it- propably I have other problems with octomap (or rgbdslam). Anyway thanks for help. This is the function I was looking for.